# How to update already inserted data in servlet based web application and java

Tags: servlets

I Want to make a "Employee Project Management" web application using java and java servlet pages for  by which user insert details of employee and assign it a project if not assigned or update the same if already assigned.
I am stuck in a situation where I am not able to update the data in database.

suggestions and solutions will be appreciated.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Just like a normal database query, write in ".java" file:

```java
PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement
    ("update emp set name=?,id=?, project=? where id=?");
stmt.setString(1, name);
stmt.setString(2, id);
stmt.setString(3, project);
stmt.setString(4, id);
stmt.executeUpdate();
```